# What is the best way to rotate around an object like "Exhibit" in the Google Cardboard app?

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

I want to rotate around a certain point based on the head movement of the user. The functionality is the same as the "Exhibit" demo in the Google Cardboard app.

Answer (score 0):

I'm extremely new to Cardboard and Unity, but this is how I modified Google's [treasure hunt sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/cardboard-unity/) for Unity 5.2.1 and Cardboard SDK 0.5.2:

- In the Unity hierarchy viewer, I selected the `Head`. In the Inspector, look for the `Cardboard Head` script, and set the `Target` property to `Cube (Transform)`.
- Edit the `CardboardHead.cs` script. In the `UpdateHead()` method, the existing code changes the rotation of the head based on the Cardboard's orientation. I changed the code to apply the rotation to the target object like so:

```cs
if (trackRotation) {
  var rot = Cardboard.SDK.HeadPose.Orientation;
  if (target == null) {
    transform.localRotation = rot;
  } else {
    //transform.rotation = target.rotation * rot;
    target.transform.localRotation = rot;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy if you are using the CardboardMain prefab.  In the Inspector for Main Camera, just displace it's Transform position backwards in Z.  It will now rotate around the point where the Head parent sits, just like the Exhibit demo.